Which redirect code should I use for version divided website?
Let's say I'm writing an HTML book hosted at https://example.com. The book would be divided into editions as time passes. There would be https://v1.example.com at first, then https://v2.example.com in a few years, then https://v3.example.com, and so on.
In the meanwhile, I would like https://example.com to redirect to the latest edition. So, https://example.com would redirect to https://v1.example.com initially, then after the 2nd edition releases, it redirects to https://v2.example.com, then in a few years after the 3rd edition releases https://v3.example.com, and so on.
Which redirect code should be used for the redirection above?
A real-world example of the pattern above is https://material.io, which redirects to https://v3.material.io. The whole series has 3 editions https://v{1-3}.material.io at the time of writing.

Material are using a 301, which I'd agree is the right type.
The old URL isn't coming back, so temporary redirects would be inappropriate, and you only need 308 in specific use-cases, which I assume will not apply to you.
(There's a nice little status codes decision chart in one of the answers to this question)
If you are keeping old copies on-line and accessible via v1, I suggest you add canonical meta tags, otherwise you'll end up with duplicate content issues and out-of-date content being indexed.  This seems the bigger SEO concern to me.  You'll also want to make it clear to users when they are viewing out-of-date content, with a link to the latest version, to keep things user-friendly.

That flow chart is awesome and great resource.
